Can なのか replace であろうと?
Can the following statement
複雑であろうと単純であろうと、状況は変わります。
be rephrased as
複雑なのか単純なのか、状況は変わります。

Both sound unnatural to me. What are you trying to say?

Whether the situation is complex or simple, it will change.

The answer is "No".

AであろうとBであろうと means "regardless of whether it's A or B".
AなのかBなのか means "whether it's A or B" (without the meaning of "regardless" or "whichever"). It's used like this:

複雑なのか単純なのか教えてください。
Please tell me whether it's complex or simple.



Here, you seem to be trying to say "whether it's A or B" with an implication of "no matter", "whichever" or "regardless". In such cases, you cannot use AなのかBなのか.

Is there a better translation for "Whether the situation is complex or simple, it will change."?

@user1602 It's better to say 状況 as early as possible to avoid confusion. And if you're referring to "the situation" (some specific situation), it might be better to add 今の, この, 現在の or something for clarity. "今の状況が単純であろうと複雑であろうと、いずれ変わることです" would sound more natural.

It is a philosophical statement, no specific situation, just any situation. So 状況が単純であろうと複雑であろうと、いずれ変わることです will be good?

@user1602 That's not bad. But if you're presenting this as a general fact, you may want to use とは and ものだ and say "状況とは単純であろうと複雑であろうと変わるものだ".
